# Populate ArrayList with Random numbers then Print Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to populate an arrayList with random numbers then print array. However I get a huge number of errors when executing the program. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class methods {
//variables
int capacity;
private static ArrayList<Double> randomArray;



public methods(int capacity) {
  //default constructor to initalize variables and call populateArray to
  //populate ArrayList with random numbers
  randomArray = new ArrayList<>(capacity); 
  populateArray();
}

 //Method that populates Array with random numbers
private void populateArray()
{

   Random rand = new Random();

   for (int i=0; i<= capacity; i++)
   {
       double r = rand.nextInt() % 256;

       randomArray.add(i,r);

   }

}
 //Get Array adds numbers to the string that is called in my main class and printed
public String getArray() {
String result = "";
for (int i=0; i<= capacity; i++)
   {
       result += String.format("%4d", randomArray);

   }
return result;

}

}

//main
public class Benchmarking {


public static void main (String args[]){

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("What is the capacity of your Array?");
     int capacity = scanner.nextInt();

   methods array1 = new methods(capacity);
   System.out.println(array1.getArray());
 }
```

After I run the program and enter the capacity it crashes. I just need to create an arrayList populate it with random numbers and print it. Here are the list of Errors I am receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException:  d   != java.util.ArrayList
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2793)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2747)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2927)
at Benchmarking.methods.getArray(methods.java:68)
at Benchmarking.Benchmarking.main(Benchmarking.java:27)
```

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong with my methods.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what errors you're seeing.

Comment: You cannot format an ArrayList as %4d. Did you mean `String.format("%4d", randomArray.get(i));` to format a specific element of the list by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass `randomArray` (which is a `java.util.ArrayList`) to `String.format()`.

You probably want to pass `randomArray.get(i)` instead.

Comment: I think that is what I was doing wrong to begin with. I got the program to run now! thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `this.capacity = capacity;` into `public methods() {` constructor to start with. You are referencing this variable but never setting it.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! I am no longer getting that error :)